# Whats the difference between 2O and O2

Tags: atoms, elements

I just saw something in a chemistry lesson what got me confused.

What is the difference between $\ce{2O}$ and $\ce{O2}$?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The 2 O represents two separate  oxygen atoms, ( not connected to one another so free to move around and react independently  ), the $\ce{O2}$ is molecular oxygen.

Comment: @Porphyrin Why dont you post it as an answer? I think its the simplest solution I've heard yet. My teacher was just talking weird stuff!

Comment: @BerryHolmes No actually not I saw that question but its not that what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $\ce{2O}$ is basically two atoms of oxygen, unbonded and separate.
2. On the other hand, $\ce{O2}$ is oxygen **molecule**, which is more commonly called oxygen gas.